# reuse action mailer template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

How do I reuse the same action mailer template for multiple mailer "actions"?

In ActionController, you can do

```
...
render :action => 'another_action'
```

I'd imagine the same thing can be done in ActionMailer, but I couldn't seem to find the right method. If it's relevant, I'm on Rails 2.3.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for render_message, there is a good example in the [API Docs Multipart Message](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) section - pasted below.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def signup_notification(recipient)
    recipients      recipient.email_address_with_name
    subject         "New account information"
    from            "system@example.com"
    content_type    "multipart/alternative"

    part :content_type => "text/html",
      :body => render_message("signup-as-html", :account => recipient)

    part "text/plain" do |p|
      p.body = render_message("signup-as-plain", :account => recipient)
      p.transfer_encoding = "base64"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the example has been removed from that page now! Also, no mention of `render_message`, it seems to of been removed as of v2.3.8. /cc @mike